# How do I modify a Ruby class?

Tags: ruby

I need to add a getlocal method to DateTime in Ruby 1.9.2, as per the suggestion on [this page](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/5344-localtime-fails-for-timewithzone-wrapped-datetimes). How do I do this? Thanks for reading

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply add data by opening a class definition like you would any other class definition.

```
class DateTime
  def getlocal
    self.to_time.getlocal.to_datetime
  end
end
```

Simply putting that in your file will monkey patch the method into the `DateTime` class.
When you open a class that already exists, you can add code to it or override existing methods.