# Access instance variable from outside the class

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

If an instance variable belongs to a class, can I access the instance variable (e.g. `@hello`) directly using the class instance?

```
class Hello
  def method1
    @hello = "pavan"
  end
end

h = Hello.new
puts h.method1
```

Answer (score 178, accepted):

Yes, you can use `instance_variable_get` like this:

```
class Hello
  def method1
    @hello = "pavan"
  end
end

h = Hello.new
p h.instance_variable_get(:@hello) #nil
p h.method1                        #"pavan" - initialization of @hello
p h.instance_variable_get(:@hello) #"pavan"
```

If the variable is undefined (first call of `instance_variable_get` in my example) you get `nil`.

---

As Andrew mention in his comment:

> You should not make this the default way you access instance variables as it violates encapsulation.

A better way is to define an accessor:

```
class Hello
  def method1
    @hello = "pavan"
  end
  attr_reader :hello  
end

h = Hello.new
p h.hello #nil
p h.method1                        #"pavan" - initialization of @hello
p h.hello #"pavan"
```

If you want another method name, you could *alias* the accessor: `alias :my_hello :hello`.

And if the class is not defined in your code, but in a gem: You can [modify classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056860/how-do-i-modify-a-ruby-class) in your code and [insert new functions to classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428847/modifying-core-classes-in-a-gem).

Comment: You should *not* make this the default way you access instance variables as it violates encapsulation.

Comment: @knut can't we just do this like `h = Hello.new` and `h.method1` and `h.hello` ?

Comment: @nlingutla You can define an accessor with `attr_reader :hello`

Comment: Wouldn't it be `alias my_hello hello`, not `alias :my_hello :hello`?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I learned alias needs symbols as parameter, so no, my version is correct and wanted as is. But I tested your code and it works also - I'm surprised about that. The documentations also use the symbols, e.g. http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/aliasing.htm

Comment: For me, this is great for specs, where you don't want to make something public.

Answer (score 27):

You can also accomplish this by calling `attr_reader` or `attr_accessor` like this:

```
class Hello
  attr_reader :hello

  def initialize
    @hello = "pavan"
  end
end
```

or

```
class Hello
  attr_accessor :hello

  def initialize
    @hello = "pavan"
  end
end
```

Calling `attr_reader` will create a `getter` for the given variable:

```
h = Hello.new
p h.hello        #"pavan"
```

Calling `attr_accessor` will create a `getter` AND a `setter` for the given variable:

```
h = Hello.new
p h.hello        #"pavan"
h.hello = "John"
p h.hello        #"John"
```

As you might understand, use `attr_reader` and `attr_accessor` accordingly. Only use `attr_accessor` when you need a `getter` AND a `setter` and use `attr_reader` when you only need a `getter`

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wants to access the variable to set, here how they can do it:

```rb
puts h.instance_variable_get(:@hello) # nil
h.instance_variable_set(:@hello, "StackOverflow") # <- set the value
puts h.instance_variable_get(:@hello) # StackOverflow
```