# Unable to access instance variable outside the class in ruby

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, attr-accessor

In my code when trying to print `p @stack` outside the class,and it shows `nil` despite putting `attr_accessor :stacks, :each_stack_size, :stack_number`. As usual it works fine and shows data when using inside the class. What am i missing?

```
class SetOfStacks
 attr_accessor :stacks, :each_stack_size, :stack_number
 # Initializing Hash to hold all the stacks and initial stack is created.
 def initialize
  @stacks = Hash.new # declaring hash to hold all stacks
  @each_stack_size = 3 # defining each stack size
  @stack_number = 1 # Current stack number
  @stacks[@stack_number] = Array.new
 end
 ...
 ...

end 
@obj = SetOfStacks.new
@obj.push(4)
@obj.push(5)
@obj.push(6)
@obj.push(7)
@obj.pop
p @stacks
```

Comment: You know what **instance** variable means, do you?

Comment: In your `initialize` method, you could also do `self.stacks = Hash.new` because `attr_accessor` is for creating getter and setter methods.

Comment: You don't need to use `attr_accessor` if you simply want to reference your instance variables (inside your class) with an `@`.

Comment: Related Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12122736/1301972

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to print an instance variable, you must access it with the context of the instance.

```
p @obj.stacks
```

Comment: Your answer will work, but your explanation is incorrect. Invoking `@obj.stacks` invokes the getter method within @obj; it only *looks* like you have direct access to the instance variable.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I simplified my answer a bit to get the point across. When you set attr_accessor, you are creating both 'getter' and 'setter' methods which allow you to read, and write to instance variables, respectively. If, for example, you only want to allow read access to an instance variable, you can set attr_reader. Although that does not purely hold true because we can override that and call instance_variable_set on the object.

Answer (score 2):

### Getter and Setter Methods

You're misunderstanding what [Module#attr_accessor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) does. Essentially, it creates getter and setter methods for your instance variables. In your case, `attr_accessor :stacks` creates the **SetOfStacks#stacks** and **SetofStacks#=** methods. Note that these are still instance methods of your object, not global variables, so you still have to invoke them properly. For example:

```
@obj = SetOfStacks.new
@obj.stacks                # invoke your getter
@obj.stacks = { foo: nil } # invoke your setter
```