# Access varible in ruby after initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to access variable in ruby after initialize, but i didn't get that variable , anything wrong in that?

```
class Test
  def initialize(params)
    @has_test = params[:has_test]
    @limit_test = params[:limit_test]
  end
  def self.method1(params)
   Test.new(params)
     #can i get that two instance variable
  end
end
```

Comment: @lurker while technically `@@` is the correct syntax most of the time as it seems in this case class instance variables would be used in place of class variables although I agree it seems he is just mistaking self and would like access to the instance variables for the instance itself.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, I agree. I didn't catch that until after my comment.

Comment: Ruby uses `#` for comments, not `//`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably set up attribute accessors, then use them this way:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :has_test
  attr_accessor :limit_test

  def initialize(params)
    @has_test = params[:has_test]
    @limit_test = params[:limit_test]
  end
  def self.method1(params)
    t = Test.new(params)
    // can i get that two instance variable
    // Yes:
    //   use t.has_test and t.limit_test
  end
end
```

Comment: Why did you decide to change `@has_test=` to `self.has_test =`? the only reason I can see for doing this is in the event that the setter performs additional operations beyond setting the instance variable. Otherwise this makes an addition method call that is unnecessary.

Comment: @engineersmnky out of whim I suppose. I changed it back.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing an instance and a class method in your example.
If this is really what you want, then you have to define an accessor with `attr_reader`:

```
class Test
  def initialize(params)
    @has_test = params[:has_test]
    @limit_test = params[:limit_test]
  end
  attr_reader :has_test
  attr_reader :limit_test
  def self.method1(params)
   obj = Test.new(params)
   p obj.has_test
   p  obj.limit_test
  end
end

Test.method1(has_test: 1, limit_test: 3)
```

It the instance/class-method is a mistake, then this example may help you:

```
class Test
  def initialize(params)
    @has_test = params[:has_test]
    @limit_test = params[:limit_test]
  end
  def method1()
   p @has_test
   p @limit_test
  end
end

obj = Test.new(has_test: 1, limit_test: 3)
obj.method1
```

If you define also the accessors like in the first code, then you have again access from outside the class.

---

Just in case you don't want a reader, see also [Access instance variable from outside the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122736/access-instance-variable-from-outside-the-class/12122761#12122761)